# Mail procedure to handle CLOB data in PLSQL

Tags: sql, package, procedure

I have a send mail procedure for sending mail. I will write procedure to fetch value from sql and pass the values to send_mail procedure to receive the mail but its giving me numeric or value error when I tries to send 1000s of record. Can some help me to rewrite my send_mail procedure to send CLOB so that size wont be  a constraint.
Below given is my procedure.

```
PROCEDURE send_mail (SUBJECT IN CLOB,MAIL_HEADER IN CLOB)
IS
      l_connection   utl_smtp.connection;
      p_smtp_hostname varchar2(200) := 'localhost';
      p_smtp_portnum varchar2(200) := '25';
      p_from varchar2(200) := 'from@mail.com';
      p_to   VARCHAR2(400) := 'to@mail.com';
   l_temp CLOB;
   p_env VARCHAR2(3000) := '';

BEGIN
   l_connection := utl_smtp.open_connection( p_smtp_hostname, p_smtp_portnum   );
   utl_smtp.helo( l_connection, p_smtp_hostname );
   utl_smtp.mail( l_connection, p_from );
   utl_smtp.rcpt(l_connection, p_to );
   utl_smtp.open_data(l_connection);
   l_temp := 'MIME-Version: 2.0' ||  chr(13) || chr(10);
   l_temp := l_temp || 'To: ' || p_to || chr(13) || chr(10);
   l_temp := l_temp || 'From: ' || p_from || chr(13) || chr(10);
   l_temp := l_temp || 'Subject: '|| SUBJECT || p_env || chr(13) || chr(10);
   l_temp := l_temp || 'Reply-To: ' ||  p_to || chr(13) || chr(10);
   l_temp := l_temp || 'Content-type: text/html;' ||
   chr(13) || chr(10) || chr(13) || chr(10);
   utl_smtp.write_data(l_connection, l_temp);
   utl_smtp.write_data(l_connection, MAIL_HEADER);
   utl_smtp.close_data(l_connection);
   utl_smtp.quit( l_connection );
 EXCEPTION
 WHEN OTHERS THEN
   RAISE;
 END send_mail;
```

Answer (score 0):

Even though, you are declaring `l_temp` as `CLOB`, This still puts you in with a limit of 32767 characters.

This is the actual declaration in `sys.utl_smtp` package. So you have your limit of characters, much less than than `CLOB`.

```
PROCEDURE WRITE_DATA(
    C     IN OUT NOCOPY CONNECTION,
    DATA  IN            VARCHAR2 CHARACTER SET ANY_CS
);
```

What you can try is, break your CLOB into chunks of `VARCHAR` variables and call `write_data` multiple times

This function can be used to split CLOB - [DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/timesten.112/e21645/d_lob.htm#TTPLP66748)

Comment: i am new in PLSQL. can u pls let me know how where I should implement this.

Comment: Still I am getting numeric or value error when i am trying to call my sen_mail procedure from the first procedure

Comment: @jabbars can you update your question with the new code you have written

Comment: @jabbars  - Another option you might have is, writing the data in a file and sending as attachment